# Wireframe and UI design for PWA

Tags: angular, react-native, progressive-web-apps

I have to create wirreframe,UI design and HTML for a project which will be based on PWA(Progressive web app)
I am confuse how to start it with?

1. wireframes will be based on mobile screen?
2. HTML using bootstrap material design or using any other tool?

Please suggest

Comment: Wireframes shoud be based on the responsive keypoints of the framework you decide to use. For the second point, it's your choice, and we can't provide an opinion-based answer for you.

Comment: So just confirm me if I am using MDB then is it a right approch?

Comment: I don't confirm anything, I don't even know what MDB is. I'm just answering your questions.